# How do I get the physical path to a mapped DIRECTORY (not a mapped drive)?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-drive, mapped-drive

I have a mapped directory in my D drive called “Inetpub”.  I point it to various folders depending which version of my website I am testing.  How do I quickly check which folder I am in when I browse to “D:\Inetpub”?

I have seen other answers for revealing the path for a network drive, but this is different.  I need to know if I’m mapped to D:\MyWebsite\QA or D:\MyWebsite\OldVersion3_2, etc.

Comment: how did you map the dir? mklink? you can view them in the command line with `dir /AL /S c:\` (will list all the symlinks on C:) or in a gui see here: http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-find-all-symbolic-links-junction-points-in-windows-7/

Comment: Yeah, I used mklink.  Thanks @FrankThomas .  Add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @FrankThomas, here is the way to get the paths via command-prompt:

```
dir /AL /S d:
```

(note - substitute different drive-letters as needed like C:, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I ended-up just using an empty text-file at the root of each of my mapped folders, like "Version_001.txt", "Version_019.txt", etc.  Then, whenever I browse to "D:\Inetpub", I glance at that file to see where I am.